# Oracle SQL - Joining Multiple Queries By the Date

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this large query below which I joined five queries by the date:

```
--Combined Daily Actions Per Revenue Source-- 
SELECT Two.the_date, 
       sp_dau, 
       cs_dau, 
       tapjoy_ios_dau, 
       tapjoy_android_dau, 
       appcircle_ios_dau, 
       appcircle_android_dau, 
       freecause_dau, 
       portal_dau 
FROM   (SELECT Trunc(Cs.create_dtime) AS The_Date, 
               Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                WHEN Cs.cs_listing_id LIKE '99999999%' THEN 
                                ( Cs.player_id ) 
                              END)    AS Sp_Dau, 
               Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                WHEN Cs.cs_listing_id NOT LIKE '99999999%' THEN 
                                ( Cs.player_id ) 
                              END)    AS Cs_Dau 
        FROM   player_chkin_cs Cs 
        WHERE  Trunc(Cs.create_dtime) >= To_date('2012-Jan-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') 
        GROUP  BY Trunc(Cs.create_dtime)) One 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Trunc(Tap.create_dtime) AS The_Date, 
                          Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                           WHEN ( Play.uuid LIKE 'i~%' ) 
                                                 OR ( Play.uuid LIKE 'ti~%' ) 
                                         THEN 
                                           Tap.player_id 
                                         END)     AS Tapjoy_Ios_Dau, 
                          Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                           WHEN ( Play.uuid LIKE 'a~%' ) 
                                                 OR ( Play.uuid LIKE 'ta~%' ) 
                                         THEN 
                                           Tap.player_id 
                                         END)     AS Tapjoy_Android_DAU 
                   FROM   player_tapjoy Tap 
                          INNER JOIN player Play 
                                  ON Tap.player_id = Play.player_id 
                   WHERE  Trunc(Tap.create_dtime) >= 
                          To_date('2012-Jan-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') 
                   GROUP  BY Trunc(Tap.create_dtime)) Two 
               ON One.the_date = Two.the_date 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Trunc(Aux.create_dtime) AS The_Date, 
                          Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                           WHEN ( Play.uuid LIKE 'i~%' ) 
                                                 OR ( Play.uuid LIKE 'ti~%' ) 
                                         THEN 
                                           Aux.player_id 
                                         END)     AS Appcircle_Ios_Dau, 
                          Count(DISTINCT CASE 
                                           WHEN ( Play.uuid LIKE 'a~%' ) 
                                                 OR ( Play.uuid LIKE 'ta~%' ) 
                                         THEN 
                                           Aux.player_id 
                                         END)     AS AppCircle_Android_DAU 
                   FROM   player_aux_pt Aux 
                          INNER JOIN player Play 
                                  ON Aux.player_id = Play.player_id 
                   WHERE  Aux.site = 'AppCircle' 
                          AND Trunc(Aux.create_dtime) >= 
                              To_date('2012-Jan-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') 
                   GROUP  BY Trunc(Aux.create_dtime))Three 
               ON Two.the_date = Three.the_date 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Trunc(Aux.create_dtime)       AS The_Date, 
                          Count(DISTINCT Aux.player_id) AS FreeCause_DAU 
                   FROM   player_aux_pt Aux 
                   WHERE  Aux.site = 'ext : freecause' 
                          AND Trunc(Aux.create_dtime) >= 
                              To_date('2012-Jan-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') 
                   GROUP  BY Trunc(Aux.create_dtime))Four 
               ON Three.the_date = Four.the_date 
       INNER JOIN (SELECT Trunc(Aux.create_dtime)       AS The_Date, 
                          Count(DISTINCT Aux.player_id) AS Portal_DAU 
                   FROM   player_aux_pt Aux 
                   WHERE  ( Aux.site = 'Portal : Promotion' 
                             OR Aux.site = 'Portal : RadiumOne' 
                             OR Aux.site = 'Portal : Paymentwall' 
                             OR Aux.site = 'Portal : TrialPay' ) 
                          AND Trunc(Aux.create_dtime) >= 
                              To_date('2012-Jan-01', 'yyyy-mon-dd') 
                   GROUP  BY Trunc(Aux.create_dtime)) Five 
               ON Four.the_date = Five.the_date
```

Most of the subqueries range from `2012-Jan-01` to present date, except for one that only have data from `09-Jul-12` to present.

So, when I run this query, the first date in the result is `09-Jul-12` and not `01-Jan-12`.

How can I get the results to start at `Jan 01`, where all but one query has relevant data for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the dates are dropping out because they do not match.  The answer to your question is `LEFT OUTER JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN`.  This keeps all rows in the first table (left side of the join), along with any matching information in the next table.  If there is no match, all the values become NULL.

Assuming that the first table has all the dates that you want, then change the join in all the subsequent queries.

If you want 0's instaed of NULL, then use `coalesce()` in the `select` clause to convert them.

Comment: Gordon-Thank you. This worked great. To attain the zeros I used NVL() instead, but I believe it produces the same result. Appreciate your help!

Comment: @Stuav . . . Yes, `NVL()` and `COALESCE()` return the same results.  However, the first is database-specific and the second is standard and so should work on any database engine.